# How to develop web application server for chatting which will accept multiple clients using TCP/IP protocol

Tags: web-services, sockets, server, chat, tcp

I want to develop a chat application which I can use as a web server which can accept multiple clients and when I put this on web I will have URL for e.g. `http://localhost:8002/index.html` and when I fire this URL in browser my page should show how many users are currently connected and can send or receive messages, but even if I close browser connection should remain alive. I am a little bit confused what should I do, I have basic knowledge of TCP/IP. Please, can anyone give me some suggestion to start with what should I learn a windows service or a web service or [Socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat) any Another concept?

Comment: The part about keeping the server-end connection open after closing the browser connection is impossible: indeed it is almost a contradiction in terms. The rest just requires you to read about a dozen tutorials: HTTP, some dynamic web-server technology, database, ... Too broad.

Comment: is there any way to keep the connection open from server side and from client side also and use URL just to see the status